# AutoLayout constraints don't affect childViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my iOS application when I add a **viewController** as a **childViewController** to another, The **autolayout constraints** is not affecting the view.

Is it any way to get ChildViewController Constraints and add them to supperView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it :

```
view.addSubview(svc.view)

let vd: [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["svc": svc.view]
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-0-[svc]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: vd))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[svc]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: vd))

svc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

From : https://gist.github.com/radianttap/4455176

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to manually add constraints to your childViewController like so;

```
UIViewController *newVC = [UIViewController new];
[self addChildViewController:newVC];
[self.view addSubview:newVC.view];

newVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *bottomContstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem:newVC.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:newVC.view
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:newVC.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:newVC.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                      multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:bottomContstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

I've used this myself and it seems to work but a more experience developer might give you something different, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But this solution not fixed the issue.

Comment: It should be noted that these are just example constraints, you'll have to create the ones correct for your situation. Also you might want to the the child VC to a container view so you'll need to swap out "self.view" with that container view.